# Xtext - how to reference an element of an element

Tags: xtext

Using the simple entity example https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html

How can I add something like the following:

```
Map:
    'map' entityA=[Entity] '.' featureA=[Feature] '=>' entityZ=[Entity] '.' featureZ=[Feature]
;
```

So that I can write:

```
entity A {
  name:String
}
entity B {
  name:String
}
map A.name => B.name
```

So that I get content assist when writing A. scoped to the features of A only?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

you usually do such things by adapting the concept of "scoping". the content assist ususally respects scoping. so adapt your scope provider like this

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl1.scoping

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EReference
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.IScope
import org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.Map
import org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl.MyDslPackage
import org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.Scopes

class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference === MyDslPackage.Literals.MAP__FEATURE_A) {
            if (context instanceof Map) {
                return Scopes.scopeFor(context.entityA.features)
            }
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE
        }
        if (reference === MyDslPackage.Literals.MAP__FEATURE_Z) {
            if (context instanceof Map) {
                return Scopes.scopeFor(context.entityZ.features)
            }
            return IScope.NULLSCOPE
        }

        super.getScope(context, reference)

    }

}
```